# Regarding the meaning of "convenient"

Tags: word-meaning

The secretary arranged a **convenient time and place** for the applicants to have an interview.

As for the sentence, I think in the phrase "convenient time", the word "convenient" means "allowing you to do something easily or without trouble"(http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/convenient) and in the phrase "convenient place",  the word "convenient" means "located in a place that is nearby and easy to get to"(http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/convenient).

Am I right? Or does  "convenient" also mean "allowing you to do something easily or without trouble" in the phrase "convenient place"?

Comment: In your specific context, the implication is ***mutually** convenient*. The interviews were scheduled with due regard to what was "easiest" for both parties (but probably mostly factoring in the *interviewees*, otherwise why bother to mention it?). Check out [convenience store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_store), which is definitely *not* "convenient" to the shopkeeper, since he often has to work 7-11 (that's 7 **a.m.** - 11 **p.m.**).

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native English speaker but I think you are right.  Actually both definitions are similar. (This word made me confused before.)

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/convenient) definitions:

1. **Suitable** for your purposes and needs and causing **the least difficulty**:

> Our local shop has very convenient opening hours.
>   A bike's a very convenient way of getting around.

2. Near or easy to get to or use :

> A very convenient bus service
>   Our new flat is very convenient for (= near to) the kids' school.

So convenient thing could be a place, time or a tool.

I think it is also often used in business mails,

> Please tell me your convenient time for our meeting

And there is a term called "[convenience store](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/convenience-store)"

Comment: Yes. Any time you try to define a word with other words you can get wrapped up in this kind of difficulty. "Convenient" can refer to a time, a place, a tool, an action, probably other things. The point is, "some WHATEVER that is reasonably easy, readily accessible, or the like".

Comment: April, you did a better job of parsing this than most native speakers would.  They would use that exact wording, but most would never stop to think that "covenient" had subtly different meanings in regard to time VS in regard to place! this is a very interesting example, because "convenient" is only used once, but distributes its different meanings over "time" and "place".